# Problems with GET trends/place (Twython)

Tags: python, twitter, twython

Trying to access just the 'name' part of trends for Toronto.
so far I have this but it is giving me errors:

```
toronto = t.get_place_trends(id=4118)

trend_array = []
for trend in toronto.trends.name:
    trend_array.append(trend) 
    print trend_array
    print trend
```

Thats after auth and returns the entire list of objects forced into an array (which cant be accessed with indexing for some reason) and as a list.

Comment: What error are you getting? Do you know what data type the return value is? You can add a print type(toronto) after the first line to confirm.

Comment: `but it is giving me errors`, would you be kind enough to let us know the errors? You cannot solve if you don't know the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, that's really strange that `toronto` returns a list that has to be accessed by indices.

Here is the code that you'll need:

```
toronto = t.get_place_trends(id=4118)
trend_array = []

if toronto:
    for trend in toronto[0].get('trends', []):
        trend_array.append(trend['name'])
        print trend_array
        print trend
```

Comment: Perfect thanks to get the output I wanted I used the last line
    print trend['name']
but that is pretty straight forward.  Such a strange way to access the information.